# 403 Forbidden doing AJAX POST from Cordova 5.0.0 app

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, cors

I have a very simple Cordova app which attempts to do an AJAX POST.

The requested URL, simple.php, looks like this :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
die ( json_encode ( array('result'=>'ok') ) );
?>
```

index.html is exactly this :

```
<head>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>


    <script>

    $(document).ready( function() {

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://drawonthe.net/simple.php',
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },

            success: function(res) {
                alert('got this res : ');
                alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            },

            error: function(err) {
                alert('got this fail : ');
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }

         });

    });

    </script>

</head>


<body>
</body>
```

My Cordova config.xml file includes the following :

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="content:///*" />
```

My app includes the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin.

I've experimented with various CSPs in index.html, but with no good result.  Eg.

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src *; ">
```

When I access this HTML page locally (from file://) I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://drawonthe.net/simple.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.` and it returns `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`.

When I access the HTML page via being hosted on a local server it works without complaint.  (The correct response: `"{\"result\":\"ok\"}"`)

When I run it as a Cordova App on either an Android or an iOS device I get `{"readyState":4, "responseText":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \" -//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">... blah blah ... 403 Forbidden ... , "status":403, "statusText": "Forbidden"}`.

What's going on?
And how do I make this request work from the phone app?

Comment: Where do you access this html pages? In your browser or in phone browser ? Where it shows success?

Comment: If I run it from a local server - or from any server in fact - for example if I upload it to here : http://brianmartin.com.au/index_so_demo.html

Comment: I see no reason why what you've done wouldn't work, but maybe you could have more luck with cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist enstead of cordova-plugin-whitelist ?

Comment: @QuickFix - a good suggestion - I was excited and tried it right away - alas, no, the same issue persists.

Comment: you are getting a response from the server, so the problem is on the server

Comment: @jcesarmobile - what kind of things could be wrong on the server that I can check?

Comment: I've just tested your code and I get this error message: "<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p>You don't have permission to access /simple.php\non this server.</p>\n<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found\nerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache Server at drawonthe.net Port 80".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved when I **disabled ModSecurity on my server**.

For me, I was able to do that via the cPanel access to my host:

cPanel > Security > ModSecurity

I hope this helps others.
Thank you @jcesarmobile for pointing out the problem had to be with the server.