# Apache cordova: only CORS requests with GET verb are accepted

Tags: cordova, cors

I'm struggling with Apache Cordova and CORS.

When I run the app in the browser everything works well, so my server must be well configured.

But when I run the application with a mobile, and the exact same requests are made to the server, only the GET requests work... I get a HTTP code 403 for POST or DELETE requests.

I have installed [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and configured it as following:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly set up a content security policy meta tag in your index.html for your Cordova application.

An example would look like this and goes in the head section of index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

There's a number of ways you can configure this to suit your security needs, there's a blog post [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) that explains in the context of a Cordova app and there's also a website [here](http://content-security-policy.com/) that explains the concept more generally.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have set `default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';` as content of the meta so I don't think that the problem comes from this.

Comment: @Simon, just have a look at these links to see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338435/ajax-post-returning-status403-statustextforbidden-cordova-android   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973290/cordova-post-request-forbidden-403-not-reaching-dispatcher-servlet  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319572/403-forbidden-doing-ajax-post-from-cordova-5-0-0-app